# Why if dag is turned off, then SparkSubmitOperator kills itself 5 minutes after startup?

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

I brought out the dag with SparkSubmitOperator. I turned it on so that it would create a task. And then turned it off so that it wouldn't create new ones. After that, I started running the task. And 5 minutes after the launch, he always sent himself a SIGTERM with log:

```
[2023-01-27 12:50:04,783] {local_task_job.py:188} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to None. Terminating instance.
[2023-01-27 12:50:04,798] {process_utils.py:100} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 968
[2023-01-27 12:50:04,802] {taskinstance.py:1265} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2023-01-27 12:50:04,804] {spark_submit.py:657} INFO - Sending kill signal to spark-submit
[2023-01-27 12:50:15,985] {spark_submit.py:674} INFO - YARN app killed with return code: 0
[2023-01-27 12:50:16,122] {taskinstance.py:1482} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1138, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1311, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1341, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 183, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 440, in submit
    self._process_spark_submit_log(iter(self._submit_sp.stdout))  # type: ignore
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 494, in _process_spark_submit_log
    for line in itr:
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1267, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
```

This error was reproduced, tried more than 5 times. But then I turned on the dag, launched it, and it worked. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

DAGs are supposed to stay unpaused for their tasks to run correctly. :)
You can limit how many DAG runs are created by setting the DAG parameter `max_active_runs` to 1 and limit how many instances of a specifc task can run at any time by setting the task level parameter `max_active_tis_per_dag` to 1. Also make sure you set the DAG parameter `catchup` to False, to avoid many runs to be scheduled if your `start_date` is a while back in the past.

This DAG should only create one running t1 task every day (based on the `@daily` schedule).

```py
from airflow import DAG
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="simple_classic_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2022,12,10),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    tags=["simple", "debug"]
) as dag:

    t1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t1", max_active_tis_per_dag=1)
```

You might find these guides helpful:

- [DAG scheduling and timetables in Airflow](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/scheduling-in-airflow) explains scheduling basics
- [Scaling Airflow to optimize performance](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-scaling-workers) goes over scaling and limit parameters